# how to troubleshoot through gcc temporary file creation

Tags: c, linux, gcc

While compiling C (not c++) code, I am getting error during link time, that certain identifiers have been defined at multiple places, but as shown below, the output is very cryptic.

Is there a way to get better messages from gcc, so that I can see which files are the cause of multiple definitions?

```
/tmp/cc8kgsLE.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `PR_SZ'
/tmp/ccDfv6U4.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc8kgsLE.o:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `PR_SEC_SZ'
/tmp/ccDfv6U4.o:(.rodata+0x8): first defined here
/tmp/cc8kgsLE.o:(.rodata+0x10): multiple definition of `PR_NSEC_SZ'
/tmp/ccDfv6U4.o:(.rodata+0x10): first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

UPDATE: Based on responses, i clarify further that
`PR_SZ`, `PR_SEC_SZ`, `PR_NSEC_SZ` are defined in ONE `.h` file, which is protected by `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif` macros..

In terms of compiling, i simply type:

```
gcc -Wall -I. -file1.c file2.c -o file2
```

UPDATE:

In addition to responses, i found the below link relevant
[global constants without using #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668385/global-constants-without-using-define)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output displayed doesn't look cryptic for me, it's very clear...
The globals variables (this is bad) `PR_SZ, PR_SEC_SZ, PR_NSEC_SZ` are defined into more than one .c files

How do you compile your project ?

Here the main problem, it's that `.o` filename doesn't match the filename of the .c file.
So to be able to see a better message you should improve your Makefile or whatever you are using to build your project.

For information :

- In `.h` the prototype of global variables declarations must be prefixed by the keyword : `extern`
- In only one `.c` file the variable should be declare normally

Comment: They also could be defined in one source file only. Typically in an `.h` file which then in turn is included by more then one `.c` file. The comment on the OP made by *simonc* is a way worth going.

Comment: they are defined in only one .h file. This .h file is included by .c files. i have made sure to protect .h file with #ifndef , #define and #endif macros. In terms of compiling i am simply writing gcc -Wall file1.c file2.c -o file2

Comment: The declaration into the `.h` must use external, if this is not the case, this is just bad coding...

Comment: I thought it's `extern`. Does `external` also do?

Comment: @Jimm #ifndef will prevent them from multiple includes in the same .c file. However, if the are being included in multiple .c files, then it will lead to the same var being defined multiple times.

Comment: @user93353 i do include same .h file across multiple .c files. But i include <stdio.h> across multiple .c and it does not complain. So are you sure that #ifndef does not protect across .c files?

Comment: Yes we are sure, gcc compile independently each .c file.
Do not mix up, prototype declaration and variable declaration

Comment: @benjarobin this is not a compile error, rather a link error. During linking, does #ifndef not protect across multiple .o files? Given my stdio.h file being included in multiple.c files, how come gcc does not complain for it?

Comment: There are no globals in `stdio.h`. @Jimm

Comment: The linker don't know anything about the language, the linker don't read source code, it doesn't event know what a .c source code is, only gcc understand it

Comment: Macros are applied even before compiling, during pre-processing! @Jimm

Comment: @Jimm what global variables does `stdio.h`contain?

Comment: @user93353 stderr, stdin, stdout

Comment: @Jimm: Regarding pre-processing you might like to have look a this answer (although answering a differnt question it might help to enlight ;-)): http://stackoverflow.com/a/13517652/694576

Comment: stdio.h doesn't declare any global variable !!! It only provide the prototype of the variable : `extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr;`

Comment: @Jimm: Verbatim from `stdio.h`: `extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr; ` Please note the use of the key word `extern`!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

In the header file

```
/* a.h */
MYEXTERN int PR_SZ; /* or whatever your variable data type is */
```

In the first .c file

```
/* a.c */
/* MYEXTERN doesn't evaluate to anything, so var gets defined here */
#define MYEXTERN 
#include "a.h"
```

In the other .c files

```
/* MYEXTERN evaluates to extern, so var gets externed in all other C files */
#define MYEXTERN extern
#include "a.h"
```

So it gets defined in only one .c file & gets externed in all the others.

Comment: Looks complicated, so why would you do this?

Comment: Yes this is a solution... Used a lot in industry.
But maybe this is too complicate to understand for a beginner.

This is used when there are a lot of global variable to declare and it's prevent to have different prototype between .c and .h file

Comment: The gain : Prevent errors... Think about this case : In the .c file you declare the variable as char, and in the .h an int. What do you think it's may happen ?

Comment: One more reason to not use (lots) of global variables.

Comment: In embedded software in some case you don't really have the choice... But yes global variable is bad, and should not be used.

Comment: @benjarobin global constants are not bad

Comment: In this case use #define or if you cannot use the keywords : const + static in the .h : It will use more memory... But you don't need to declare the variable in the .c file